# How can I create this simple search form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Basically I have three pages.

```
-A page with all possible search results for example:
'search result 1'
'search result 2'
'search result 3'
-I have a page with a search form and enter button.
-And I have a results page, which displays results.
```

So, I type "result 1" into the search form, hit the enter button, then on a new page (the results page), the results come up which would be 
search result 1

How can I do this my friends? I am a noob at this sort of stuff so links, tutorials, etc. would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these -

http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/simple-sql-search

http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/search/index.html

http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/creating-a-form-that-will-search-a-mysql-database#.TvK4lfI4n9o

Comment: I believe the first link answers my question. Many thanks to you user1110394 <3

Comment: @user1109075, while thanks is always appreciated, a user would always prefer an up vote or an answer acception

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google search engine on your own website.

http://www.google.com/cse/

It's super reliable, fast and easy to use.

Comment: No, I know how to use, I just really wanted to make my own search engine like i described it. Google's search engine is kinda not my style.